# rsync over direct ethernet connection slows down quickly

Tags: networking, ethernet, rsync

I've connected two Ubuntu Server 20.04 machines with a direct ethernet connection. One is a computer with a RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller, the other is a Raspberry Pi 4 with gigabit ethernet adapter.

After connecting the two machines via

```
sudo ip ad add 10.0.0.101/24 dev enp4s0
sudo ip ad add 10.0.0.104/24 dev eth0
```

I set up an rsync service on the raspberry pi 4, and then I begin an rsync of a large from the other machine with

```
rsync --partial --inplace --append --progress file.file rsync://10.0.0.104:/hdd1
```

Initially, the file transfer starts a speed of 75 MB/s reported by rsync. But after a few seconds it slows down to 10 MB/s. If I kill the rsync, wait a while, and then restart it, it resumes at 75 MB/s.

Why is the speed dropping so quickly and how can I make it persist at 75 MB/s?

Comment: I don't think you can.  With things like transfer speed, I rarely consider very seriously the transfer speed reported after a few seconds.  The long term transfer speed is more useful.  So, rather than thinking 75 MB/s is the norm, you should think 10 MB/s is the norm and that you got a few seconds of 75 MB/s...  `rsync` is single threaded.  Perhaps you can consider using the GUI-based `Filezilla`?  It can have up to 10 simultaneous transfers.

Comment: To be more precise (I can edit my question if needed), the speed is actually fluctuating between 75 MB/s and 10 MB/s or lower. I confirmed with `dstat` that the network is bursting for a few seconds at 75 MB/s and then dropping below 10. Perhaps some other resource is being strained such as disk or memory?  https://i.imgur.com/DWQ8yG0.jpg

Comment: I also noticed using `htop` that the rsync process is often in the `D` state (uninterruptable sleep). Which leads me to believe it's waiting for disk

Comment: Possible.  But I think if you start up `Filezilla`, then you can also find out for sure.  I mean, if your bottleneck is the disk, then it performing 10 or just 4 file transfers would theoretically be impossible.  At least you can find the "sweet spot" -- the maximum number of simultaneous transfers you can do that uses the minimum elapsed time.  If you find out the number is `1`, then that also answers your question about `rsync`...

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think you can do too many simultaneous read/writes to/from the SD card attached to a Raspberry Pi...  Don't start with `10` in your tests...

Comment: I think I confirmed it's the read from the SSD that's slow. When I try to rsync from an external HDD, it is much faster. I am only doing 1 file transfer at a time (very large file)

Comment: Also to clarify: I'm writing to an external HDD on the raspberry pi 4 as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122437/discussion-between-mark-and-ray).